# How to do #{id} section navigation withing same blazor(.razor) page?

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I am trying too navigate to different sections in blazor(.razor) page. Looked through various post but no help.....

Comment: Are you talking about navigate to an anchor ?

Comment: Build an AnchorLink component.  [This is a pretty good guide](https://mikaberglund.com/2019/12/28/creating-anchor-links-in-blazor-applications/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Please refer the below code snippets



 @page "/navigate"
    @inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

    <h1>Navigate in Code Example</h1>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="NavigateToCounterComponent">
        Navigate to the Counter component
    </button>

    @code {
        private void NavigateToCounterComponent()
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("counter");
        }
    }
```

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: For my understanding this routs to a different page named "counter" not to a specific section on the same page.

Comment: same page navigate with different name.

"/"                                                                                                                                    
and
"/counter"

Answer (score 0):

For Links to Ancestor there is a tools from DevExpress [DevExpress.Blazor.AnchorUtils](https://github.com/DevExpress/Blazor/tree/master/tools/DevExpress.Blazor.AnchorUtils)

with this you can define a AnchorLink

```
<AnchorLink class="nav-link py-3 px-4" href="#MySection1">My Section 1</AnchorLink>
```

for more information see the link.